# Restrict AWS DynamoDB access from particular AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

Using Dynamo DB for my application. I have some critical reference values and want to keep those in DynamoDB. I am not very sure about this but can we have a policy or way to restrict that DynamoDb table access from any VPC?

Thanks
Kiran

Answer (score 3):

Limiting access from a VPC is not possible, since DynamoDB operates as a regional manage service outside your VPC.

However there are several other ways to implement access control to Dynamodb.
1) Using IAM user access keys and policies
2) Using federated access control using Cognito/User Pools or Amazon STS

Note: If you need more granularity of access, you can use Dynamodb [fine grained access control mechanisms](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html). If your data are highly sensitive try considering Amazon KMS.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a VPC endpoint on your DynamoDB and configure appropriate ACL's for a table.

Further reading for you

Best Practice:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/best-practices-security-preventative.html

VPC Endpoints:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints-ddb.html

Ashan is correct that you cannot have multiple DynamoDB instances per region.