# AWS DynamoDB is always internet facing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-vpc

## Question

Tried to find a way to put DynamoDB in a VPC but could not find so far.

For Lambda, it can be inside a VPC with ENI having an IP from a VPC subnet, and then the Lambda does not have any internet connectivity without NAT.

Please confirm, DynamoDB has no such feature and it is always internet facing, although we can route the traffic not to go to the Internet via DynamoDB VPC endpoint.

Comment: What you say is correct.

Answer (score 4):

That is correct. You can use IAM policies with conditions to limit access to within a VPC, however. [Restricting Access to a Specific VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies-vpc-endpoint.html#example-bucket-policies-restrict-access-vpc)

Comment: It looks limit access from VPC is not applicable to DynamoDB as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42969560/restrict-aws-dynamodb-access-from-particular-aws-vpc. The document is about S3.

Comment: It's true that you cannot global restrict access to DynamoDB to a VPC, but you can limit the access for an individual policy to require it to come from a VPC. You can apply that limitation to all policies that have access.

Comment: @JasonWadsworth is this applicable for DynamoDB streams also? though I tried and not able to do. Not sure what I am missing

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I'd have to look at the streams conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Your are right, DynamoDB always internet-facing. Is it bother you? Access to DynamoDB denied without IAM authentication

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It does not bother but just to double confirm that there is no such option like Lambda to put into VPC for DynamoDB.

Comment: You can get access to DynamoDB from your VPC via VPC Endpoints, but it’s not restricting Internet access to tables. It’s only for latency improvement

Answer (score 1):

**DynamoDB Preventative Security Best Practices -**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/best-practices-security-preventative.html

TLDR, main points -
1. Use IAM policy conditions for fine-grained access control
2. Use a VPC endpoint and policies to access DynamoDB
3. Encryption at rest
4. Use IAM roles