# DynamoDB Streams can be access(from lambda) using VPC endpoints for DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

DynamoDB Streams can be access(from lambda) using VPC endpoints for DynamoDB ?

I understand this for DynamoDB: VPC endpoints for DynamoDB support IAM policies to simplify DynamoDB access control, where access can be restricted to a specific VPC endpoint. also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60593813/aws-dynamodb-is-always-internet-facing)

As per this [link](https://jayendrapatil.com/aws-dynamodb-advanced/#VPC_Endpoints), `DynamoDB Streams cannot be access using VPC endpoints for DynamoDB`
Is this correct? any alternative?

its all in same region

Comment: Right. How about using triggers where the lambda runs in a VPC and gets data passed to it as part of invocation?

Comment: @hunterhacker if I understand it correctly - its more of lambda invoked as soon as a new record is posted on ddb stream. do you mind sharing some pointers on this approach?

Comment: @lowLatency - Did you find any solution to this problem. I am facing the same issue. Lambda is able to attach a trigger when not inside VPC but fails to do so when it is inside the VPC